# Cannot destructure property 'success' of 'userUpdateProfile' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

My screen is not showing up, I have this due in the next 24 hours and would appreciate some help, i would be greatful if i had assistance, i have been working really hard to make this work. assistance would be greatly appreciated and a big thank you will occur to your amazing answers

error screen(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKeFG.png)

useraction.js

```
export const getUserDetails = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_DETAILPROFILE_REQUESTED,
    })

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState()

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    }
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/users/${id}`, config)

    dispatch({
      type: USER_DETAILPROFILE_SUCCESSFUL,
      payload: data,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_DETAILPROFILE_FAILED,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    })
  }
}

export const updateUserProfile = (user) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATEDPROFILE_REQUESTED,
    })

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState()

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    }
    const { data } = await axios.put(`/api/users/profile`, user, config)

    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATEDPROFILE_SUCCESSFUL,
      payload: data,
    })

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL,
      payload: data,
    })

    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_UPDATEDPROFILE_FAILED,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    })
  }
}
```

Profile screen:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Button, Row, Col, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import { getUserDetails, updateUserProfile } from '../actions/userActions'
import { USER_UPDATEDPROFILE_RESET } from '../constants/userConstants'

const ProfileScreen = ({}) => {
  const [userName, setName] = useState('')
  const [userEmail, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [userPassword, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('')
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null)

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.userDetails)
  const { loading, error, user } = userDetails

  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
  const { userInfo } = userLogin

  const userUpdateProfile = useSelector((state) => state.userUpdateProfile)
  const { success } = userUpdateProfile

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!userInfo) {
      navigate('/login')
    } else {
      if (!userInfo.name) {
        dispatch(getUserDetails('profile'))
        dispatch({ type: USER_UPDATEDPROFILE_RESET })
      } else {
        setName(userInfo.name || success)
        setEmail(userInfo.email)
      }
    }
  }, [dispatch, navigate, userInfo, user, success])
```

I have been trying to debug this and cant work out why it is not working

Comment: You are trying to destructure a value from undefined variable. Quick fix is return empty object from your selector as default value or do not destructure and use the dot notation to access the property like `userUpdateProfile.success`

Comment: could you please explain further @Fiju , i am new to programming

Comment: It appears your reducer/action is not returning an object that contains a property named `success` - you've not included your reducer/action code here so it is nearly impossible to determine why this is happening. Can you include your reducers please?